# I am trying to post to a facebook group using koala gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

So far I have the following code:

```
def to_facebook
  if self.post_on_facebook == true
    self.user.facebook.put_wall_post("message")
  end
end
```

Which allows me to click a checkbox to "post on facebook" and it was post on the users wall "message" . I want to put the "message" on a facebook group.

Answer (score 2):

figured it out after some digging.
 I needed put_connections(group_id, "feed", :message => "post you want on group feed")

ie:

> self.user.facebook.put_connections(15171xxxxxxxx, "feed", :message => "Test page wall post")